# Printing a list whose elements are class objects

Tags: python, object, printing

I am trying to print a list whose elements are all objects of a user defined class, as in this simple example:

```
class Athing:
    def __init__(self,thething):
      self.aray = thething

  # Representation of thing for printing
  def __str__(self):          
      return '['+ ', '. join(str(i) for i in self.aray) + ']'

this_thing = []
for j in range(2):
    this_thing.append(Athing([[j,j+2,j+3], [j*2,j+5,j+6]]))
print 'this_thing =\n',this_thing
print 'this_thing[0] =\n',this_thing[0]
```

The code above gives me the following results:

```
this_thing =
[<__main__.Athing instance at 0x109dec368>, <__main__.Athing instance at 0x109dec3f8>]
this_thing[0] =
[[0, 2, 3], [0, 5, 6]]
```

Why can't the list of `Athing` objects print them without explicitly 
asking for the object, as in the second print, and how can I make 
the first print work?

Comment: You need to define `__repr__` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing a list containing objects uses `__str__` for the list itself, but the implementation of `list.__str__` calls `__repr__` for each object - Athing() in your case.

So you want to override `__repr__` and you won't have to override `__str__` since :

> If a class defines **repr**() but not **str**(), then **repr**() is
>   also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of
>   that class is required